# Group Policy testing

Tags: group-policy

How do I go about testing a Group Policy before applying it to an entire OU?

I currently have an OU with many users within the OU.  I want to test the Group Policy on one of these users before applying it to everyone in the OU.  The Group Policy is very simple, i.e. changing the proxy settings in Internet Explorer.

As I have never used Group Policies before (I've just read a tutorial about it from Microsoft's website).

I have created the Group Policy (just changed to proxy to something which doesn't exist), but don't know how to apply it to a single user.

Comment: Create a test user group and feat user with the hours policies.

Comment: So if I create a test user group (is that the same thing as a test OU?), can I leave myself in the existing OU and add myself into the test OU too?  I was about to move myself from my current OU to a test OU, but got a warning from the Group Policy Editor that this action might stop the AD from working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always a good idea to create a test OU in your AD tree to apply and test new policies.  That way you can apply the policy just to that OU and make sure everything works.  I keep a couple of virtual machines in that OU.   This makes it easy to recover if the GP breaks something on the machine.  I take a snapshot before applying the GP and restore the snapshot if necessary.

I also create some test users as well for that OU.  One user with admin/domain admin privileges and one without.  That way I can see how the GP affects each type of user.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two Microsoft article with recommendations and steps for using test OU's to try out your GPO settings before deploying them into production.  I found these very helpful when I first setup my GPO testing strategy:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738966%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391023.aspx

I hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

In the Group Policy Management console, you can use Security Filtering to restrict the GPO to a specific User/Computer.

By default, the GPO will apply to Authenticated Users in the linked Organizational Unit (every user and computer basically).  You can remove Authenticated Users and replace it with a specific account or groups.

Is your proxy setting user level or computer level?  Computer Settings in the GPO are applied regardless of the specific user logged in.  So in that case you need to restrict it based on Computer Account.

Also, make sure your OU links are correct.